# Automatically remove email addresses not in Global Address book?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have a large list of descriptive names (i.e. not of the format `myemail@example.com` but using the person's real name), separated by semi colons, that I would like to put into the To: field in Outlook.

For example:

```
Joe Blow; Ali Sally; First Last; Example Ex
```

The problem is, some of these email accounts have been deactivated and I would like to know if there's a way to automatically ignore them if the auto resolver can't resolve them? For a list with 100 email addresses and 10 duds, it's tedious task to go through each manually to remove. Is there a setting that could delete an email address if the auto resolver doesn't resolve if it's not in the address book? If there is no setting, would it be possible to write a program that does this, does Outlook offer APIs with such a capability?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a free [Sort Message Recipients](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesSortRecipients) utility you can use for that. After installing it, create a new message, paste your recipient list, click the "Check Names" button on Outlook ribbon and after that run the "Sort Message Recipients" tool also on the ribbon. It will remove all recipients that were not resolved automatically. Please note that I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers.